# Android Studio library not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I need to code a library that will help me on Android and Java.
I follow these steps:

- I create a new Android Library
- I implement it with File > New > Import Module

But I cannot use functions and voids contained into library: How can I create a library (that contains functions, booleans, arrays, ecc..) And use it into an Android Application?

Answer (score 1):

Please, make sure the library is listed at the top of your settings.gradle file, as shown here for a library named "my-library-module":

```
include ':app', ':my-library-module'
```

Check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html), hope it helps.